# Is there a way to see the contents of the Core Data store while the app is running?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-data

Is there a way (within XCode or a 3rd party application) to see the Core Data store as the application is running?

Since Core Data relies on an SQLite database in the background, is there a way to view the database behind it, what it contains, how it changes?

Answer (score 1):

- You can get Core Data to log output by passing arguments on launch

  ```
  -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
  ```
- If you are using the simulator you can navigate to the app on your dev machine and look at the sqlite file.
- If you are using a device you can access the sqlite file using organizer

Comment: Don't forget, you can get different levels of detail by passing 1, 2, or 3 as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is a built-in way in Xcode to open/view you SQLite Database.
But, if you're running your application in the simulator, you can easily open the sqlite-database with an sqlite-viewer of your choice.

The default path would be:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<IOS_VERSION>/Applications/<APPLICATION_UID>/Documents
```

The filename of the sqlite-db depends on your NSPersistentStoreCoordinator implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/), very easy to use and user friendly, it has a trial version for free or you can of course buy the full version.

I'm using the trial version ("15-minute sessions and custom queries only return 5 rows.") and I'm very pleased..

You can locate your simulator .sqlite file in:
/Macintosh HD/Users/"username"/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/"current iOS development version"/Applications/"your app directory(some long number)"/Documents/"someNumber_projectName.sqlite"

*** You will have a problem locating the ~/Library folder if you have Lion installed because it's hidden. Check [this post](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/22/access-user-library-folder-in-os-x-lion/) that shows how to reveal it.

Comment: I like Base, and it's relative inexpensive, even if you only use it to help setup and debug Core Data programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

When running a Core Data app on macOS, or with iOS in a simulator, you can use **Core Data Lab** to track changes while running the app. This dedicated Core Data viewer contains a data change tracker that displays new, deleted and mutations with distinct colours.

More info here: https://betamagic.nl/products/coredatalab.html

*Disclaimer*: I'm the creator of this app.